# Is there some better way just to keep the duplicated rows in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am just curious if pandas has a easier way just to keep the duplicated rows ?

Pls dont understand me wrong. I have such a problem, because I unintented get the Pandas Dataframe wrong and have to work with the duplicated rows manuelly.

Thank you all!

Comment: yes, there are better ways to keep the duplicated rows in Pandas! ;)

Comment: Try always to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when asking questions. In case of _pandas_ questions please provide sample _input_ and _output_ data sets (5-7 rows in CSV/dict/JSON/Python code format _as text_, so one could use it when coding an answer for you). This will help to avoid _situations_ like: `your code isn't working for me` or `it doesn't work with my data`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas has a .duplicated() method for the DataFrame class that allows you to find duplicated columns.

```
>>> df = DataFrame([[1,2,3],[3,4,6],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]],columns=['T1','T2','T3'])

>>> df
    T1  T2  T3
0   1   2   3
1   3   4   6
2   1   2   3
3   1   2   2

>>> df[df.duplicated(keep=False)]
    T1  T2  T3
0   1   2   3
2   1   2   3
```

You can also look for duplicates only within certain columns using the subset argument.

```
>>> df[df.duplicated(keep=False,subset='T1')]
    T1  T2  T3
0   1   2   3
2   1   2   3
3   1   2   2
```